# Create a list that lets appear an element

Tags: html

I'm new in web design and in web development, and I found myself in trouble while I was designing a website. Actually I'm working on Wordpress, but I have to customize a page "by hand", because it's the only way for accomplishing this task. My aim is to create a list in which each list item will make appear an element somewhere in the page. Specifically I should have a collapsible list where each "subitem" click lets a new list appear on the right, where this new list is different from the others.
Now, my question is, how can I do this? How can I "link" a subitem with a hidden list that will result visible clicking on the specific subitem? Does anybody indicate me the right way to pursue at least ( such as using CSS, Javascript, HTML, ... ) ?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.
I hope someone could help me

Comment: It sounds like you're jumping into a project without knowing the basics. I recommend finding tutorials on Javascript, HTML and CSS for starers.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, look into using things like this:

```
var new_div = document.createElement("div");
var node = document.createTextNode("This div is new.");
new_div.appendChild(node);

var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(new_div);
```

to make an element appear, the `createElement` is used (creates html tag) you can then style the element using `setAttribute()` or `removeAttribute()`,
and to link the new content to the list items, the `getElementById` is used (each item in the list needs its own id to identify it, if each item does different things).